# how to determine if an object is not initialized in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to determine if an object is not initialized, and how can we detect it in kotlin
kindly need a solution stuck in this there is an error coming object is not intialized,
i m calling that object from Junit test , but the object is throwing error not intialized i want to check

Comment: Please be more explicit and perhaps include code sample. Do you mean a lateinit property or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullable types and the null check to determine if an object has been initialized or not. Something like this:

```
val myObject: MyObject? = MyObject()
if (myObject != null) {
    
} else {
    // Object is not initialized (null)
}
```

Comment: I m using RIBS architecture, the issues comes in when i m calling presenter object

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what exactly you mean under "object" and "initialized", but I'll try to imagine.

So you have an object

```
object MyObject {
    private var initialized = false
    private lateinit var data: String

    fun initialize(data: String) {
        this.data = data
        initialized = true
    }

    fun plus(str: String) = initialized {
        "$data $str"
    }

    private fun <T> initialized(block: () -> T): T {
        if (!initialized) {
            throw RuntimeException("uninitalized")
        }

        return block()
    }
}
```

And now you can test it

```
class Test {
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException::class)
    fun `Have to throw RuntimeException if not initialized`() {
        // Set

        // Do
        MyObject.plus("aaa")

        // Check
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException::class)
    fun `Plus have to return correct value`() {
        // Set
        MyObject.initialize("bbb")

        // Do
        val result = MyObject.plus("aaa")

        // Check
        assert(result == "bbb aaa")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by object and initialization you mean a late init property, then you need to access the `KProperty` reference of your property.

```
lateinit var myObject: MyObject

if (this::myObject.isInitialized) {
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the previous answer, if the object is a lateinit variable, you can use the isInitialized property to check if it has been initialized. Something like this:

```kotlin
lateinit var myObject: MyObject

if (this::myObject.isInitialized) {
    
} else {
    // Object is not initialized
}
```

Comment: Please, use "comment" if you want to comment about an answer.